# Multiple Variable data frame diff

Tags: r, casting, diff, apply

I have a `data.frame` which looks like that:

```
AsofDate    PeriodStartDate   Price
2007-12-01  2008-01-01        8
2007-12-01  2008-04-01        10
2007-12-01  2008-10-01        16
2007-12-01  2009-01-01        29
2007-12-02  2008-01-01        8
2007-12-02  2008-04-01        10
2007-12-02  2008-10-01        16
2007-12-02  2009-01-01        29
```

I would like to calculate the difference between each adjacent quarter per day.

So I would like to have a quick way to create one time serie per difference of quarter with the different the timestamp.

I have tried to pivot it, or to use `by` but it does not work very well.

Comment: You could try `diff`

Comment: df<-by(df[,3],df$AsofDate,diff) this what I am doing, but then I am losing the information about which quarter I am differencing

Comment: You may have to add `function(x) c(NA, diff(x))`

Comment: In `dplyr`, it is `df %>% group_by(AsofDate) %>% mutate(Pricediff=Price-lag(Price))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R you could do

```
df$diff <- unlist(tapply(df$Price, df$AsofDate, function(x) c(NA,diff(x))))

> df
AsofDate PeriodStartDate Price diff
1 2007-12-01      2008-01-01     8   NA
2 2007-12-01      2008-04-01    10    2
3 2007-12-01      2008-10-01    16    6
4 2007-12-01      2009-01-01    29   13
5 2007-12-02      2008-01-01     8   NA
6 2007-12-02      2008-04-01    10    2
7 2007-12-02      2008-10-01    16    6
8 2007-12-02      2009-01-01    29   13
```